# Command + V not working with keyup event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, macos, keyup

I've have the following scenario and bellow a small jQuery script:

I have an **`input`** and the **`keyup`** event attached to it

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.info(e.ctrlKey, e.metaKey, e.keyCode);
});
```

All of us know what this does, it should print to the console, either the `ctrl` key was pressed durring the event (`boolean` value), either the Meta key (in my case, `Command` key) was pressed during the event (another `boolean` value) and the Key code (`int` value).

**Nothing unusual, but…**

It looks like when pressing the `command` key, the `keyup` event is suppresed for any other key when pressing it.

In case of pressing `ctrl + v` (**ctrl, not command**) it throws `true false 86` - which is great, the `ctrl` was pressed when the `v` key was released and the keyCode is 86 (for `v`) and after it throws `false false 17` - which is also great, the event was fired after releasing the `ctrl` key.

Weel, when pressing `command + v`, it only throws **`false false 91`** which means that the event was triggered only once (when `command` key was released), instead of twice. It should have thrown `false true 86` (no ctrl key, but meta key with `v`) and after that `false false 91` (when releasing `command`).

**Is this a jQuery bug, a Mac OS X limitation or I'm doing something wrong?**

**How can I make it work?**

Thanks!

PS: I need the `keyup` event because I need the text pasted to input to make some processing on it. I also need `command + v` because I need the pasted value :)

PS2: On Windows OS I think it's working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `paste` event.

```
$('input').on('paste', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($('input').val());
    }, 0);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6zwp/3/)

The `setTimeout` function is necessary so that the input's value is for sure updated before a call is made to retrieve it. You can pass `this` to the `setTimeout` in a number of ways.

**option 1** (add to the window object or declare global variable)

```
$('input').on('paste', function(e) {
    window.input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(input.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6zwp/8/)

**option 2** (pass variable to another function)

```
$('input').on('paste', function(e) {
    var input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        inputVal(input);
    }, 0);
});

function inputVal(input){
    console.log(input.val());
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6zwp/7/)

Comment: `paste`, nice event! I didn't know about it, but is there a way to avoid `setTimeout`? (I have a lot of stuff to do processing the input's value and this looks like a 'hack'). The code pasted at jsfiddle does not work in IE9 and below, due to it's different approach of `setTimeout` which doesn't support parameters to be passed to the function :(

Comment: For what I needed, I used `$('form').on('submit', function(e) {…})`, and from `setTimeout` function I just triggered the submit event of that form, **thanks a lot**!